# How to reference vector based data to raster data that already has spatial reference in MAPublisher?

Tags: vector, coordinate-system

I have been able to load in raster data into MAPublisher and properly registered it, however, I have been having trouble with a further step. I am trying to reference vector data that has no GCS or projection to the raster data's spatial information. The vector data is in pdf format, and I would like to be able to reference it and export it in an ESRI-supported format. I have been able to size the vector data to match the raster data, but every time I try to register it to the raster data, it makes it incredibly large and goes off the canvas. Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got at least one other layer to use as a reference, you can use the guide in chapter 2 of the tutorial guide, as [mentioned on the Avenza forum](http://www.avenza.com/forum/index.php?topic=457.msg959#msg959). Similarly, someone mentions using the same approach iteratively to match up two layers [on Cartotalk](http://www.cartotalk.com/lofiversion/index.php?t2393.html). You should be able to get a reasonable approximation through that approach, failing this, you'd likely have to use georeferencing in a full GIS package, such as the georeferncer plugin in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).